# How to copy a line from terminal

Tags: go

Is there a way to copy the current line of terminal characters in Go? I want to replace what the user is typing in the console with the program output. Then I want to paste what he typed on the next line so he can continue what he was typing. The output will look cleaner. Otherwise the program output comes between what he was typing.

Below are parts of two concurrent functions:

```
for {
    // print username before typing field in consoles
    fmt.Print(username, ": ")
    // read the message from the user
    message, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

The above allows user to send messages, remaining code is omitted as it is not part of the problem

The below receives the message from some other source

```
// set message display format
    msgDisplay := "%s : %s"
    // populate the message to the display format
    msgDisplay = fmt.Sprintf(msgDisplay, t.Username, t.Message)
    // print message on console
    fmt.Println(msgDisplay)
```

You can deduce that this is similar to chatting, Imagine a user is typing in the send messages part and there was an incoming message from some other source. eg: user "Jojo" was typing "fabrication", incoming message from "Renu" was "2019" reached before the "Jojo" finished typing, The console is supposed to look

> Renu: 2019
>   Jojo: fabrication

Current behaviour

> Jojo: fabrRenu: 2019

Jojo was in the midst of typing the message and the incoming message interupted with the input visually. If Jojo continued typing, it'll look

> Jojo: fabrRenu: 2019cation

The program works correctly, the destination receives "fabrication", but visually it's not correct

Comment: What is "the current line of terminal characters"?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want to achieve, for the time being try looking at the [terminal package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal)

Comment: @Flimzy Consider the user is typing an input, imagine a program output from a concurrent process is output on the console. Now visually, if the user wanted to type “fabrication”, and the program output was 2019, the user typed “fab” and the program output “2019”, its gonna look fab2019. I want to replace fab with 2019 and put fab on the next line so the user can continue typing.

Comment: Please show your current code with the undesired behavior. That will be much easier than trying to imagine what you're talking about.

Comment: Most commonly, this kind of problem is solved by logging the output to a file and following the logfile in a separate window (`tail -f` on Unix). You can then only use the initial window for input, problem solved. :) If you really want to manipulate the typed line, be warned, as this is a very deep rabbit hole to go into. If you really want to, the place to start is the "curses" module

Comment: @MiłoszŁakomy This is a good advice. Editing the terminal output will be a hectic and bad idea.

Comment: @Flimzy I have updated the question with the code and example. I'm going to listen to  MilozLakomy's advice, But being able to edit terminal output would be fun i guess.

Comment: @Abel Thanks for your feedback and good luck!